# Is there a way I can shut down this phishing website?

Tags: phishing

I found a fake PayPal phishing website, and I want to shut it down, I have run my script that sends many requests to this website with randomize emails and password, but it is not fully shut it down.

When I refresh the website it takes like 10 sec to load, but it is  still working, it seems like this website is powerful...

Are there any suggestions to shut down this website?

I'm currently searching for phishing websites, and so far I've dropped two phishing sites, that's my job.

Comment: Providing info on how to DoS a site is not what we do here. Asking us to DoS it for you is not what we do either. I doubt very much if DoS'ing stuff is your job. You might think of it as your mission, but it is not your job. If, on the very off chance, that it is your job, then you need to speak to your supervisor for options, not random strangers.

Comment: If you find a fake PayPal site, report it to them: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/security/report-problem. They have teams with both the technical and legal knowledge and the contacts to take sites like these down in a very efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

> so far I've dropped two phishing sites, that's my job

Really? In a lot of jurisdictions what you describe that you are doing is illegal. More generally it is known as vigilantism, and it is hard to conceive of a business model where your employer would generate revenue from you attacking sites.

It is highly possible that the person paying for the hosting of the site may be completely unaware that the facility is being used this way. If you want to do something constructive, then sign up to some of the RBL lists and submit the URL there, also learn how to identify and notify the legitimate operator of the hosting and the organization being impersonated (Paypal in this instance).

Comment: it is legal if I do this as part of my job, have you never heard of cyber units?

Comment: No. I also find it *very* hard to believe that any legitimate organization would perceive that such an approach is ethically justified.

Comment: Do you think this is unjustified? That this such of sites steal information and ruin people's lives?

Comment: I am sure the IRA, the Afghani Mujadeen, Boko Haram, the Klu Kux Klan and a lot of other organizations really believe what they are doing is justified. That you don't seem to have made any attempt to achive your end via legitimate means paints you in a very poor light.

Comment: @nakE you are part of a cyber unit and you came ***here*** to figure out who to report a site to?

Comment: @schroeder Why not ?